# Problem trying to cast generically a derived templated class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, casting, derived-class

I'm trying to cast a template derived class to a parent class without knowing it's type.

This is a simplification of the code I have :

```
/* Base Class */
class Base {};

/* Templated derived Class */
template<typename T>
class ATemplate : public Base {  
  public:
    T GetData();

  private:
    T _data;
};

/* Derived class */
template<typename T>
class Derived : public ATemplate<T> {
};

void main() {
    std::vector<Base*> vector;
    vector.push_back(new Derived<int>());

    for (auto var : vector) {
        if (dynamic_cast<ATemplate</* I don't know the type of this class*/>>) {
           /* Do stuff */
        }
    }
}
```

I have a list of Base and I want to dynamic_cast each class of this list to ATemplate.

I would like not to have one cast for each type I created. A friend (cc killian.G) told me I could maybe use std::variant.
Someone know if what I'm asking is possible ?

Comment: Generally `dynamic_cast` is code smell.  Normally what you would do here is make a interface in the base class using virtual functions and then use the virtual dispatch mechanism to handle the call to those virtual functions implemented by the derived class.

Comment: dont you know the type? It is `ATemplate<int>` in your example

Comment: `dynamic_cast` only works with at least a `virtual` destrucor function at the base. You might be interested to have a lookk at the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)

Comment: You don’t have a vector of `Derived<int>` like you think you do. Your `push_back` is slicing your object: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing

Comment: @user463035818, Yes I don't know the type cause I could have double, int, some enums or more

Comment: Tell me if the dupe is wrong or don't answer the question.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot sorry but your link don't answer my question

Comment: Your friend is correct that `std::variant` is most likely the right tool here.

Comment: @MaxLanghof, thx for the answer but do you have any example on how I would use std::variant in my case ?

Comment: @starkmax You could start at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit which has a good example (and may look scary), but there is plenty of material available online to become familiar with `std::variant` and `std::visit`. The linked duplicate is also relevant (the visitor section), it just doesn't use `std::variant` (but the same concept).

Comment: @starkmax I added a variant example to the other question

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Thx for the help ! I'll use std::variant